# how to stop Directory.CreateDirectory creating parents?

Tags: c#, parent, create-directory

I know that `Directory.CreateDirectory` actually creates parents, so how can I STOP this from happening? i.e. is there a mode that I can utilise like a `stricter` way of doing so, the reason is that I have a watch program watching the parent top tree dir and it goes beserk if `Directory.CreateDirectory` makes more than one dir at a time.

Is there an equivalent to `Directory.CreateDirectory` which will NOT make parents?

Comment: But think this: If the method is not allow to create parent, if parent not exists? does it throw an exception?

Comment: Please add at the very least - add examples of the parent directories youb claim are being created. You could use your watch program to advise you.

Comment: A small combination of [`Directory.GetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`Directory.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) should be trivial to implement.

Comment: no, this is imprecise since no parents need exist EG: folder `C:\test` exists and `C:\test\this\is\the\folder\to\make` does not exist there is no other way then recursively walking up that long path checking each time because those paths, none of them exist, THEN making them one at a time BEFORE then doing that final check you mention. I am asking if there is an easier way to TRY to make it then recursion only if it fails

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but it should be easy to make one using the two functions I highlighted.  There is no need for recursion, just get the parent of the one you want to create.  If the parent exists, call `Directory.CreateDirectory`.  If it doesn't, don't call it - then it won't create all the missing ones.  If that isn't what you need, please edit your question for more clarity.

Comment: Also please don't assume that people commenting on your question did/didn't downvote (or upvote) your question.  Voting is [deliberately anonymous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95603/why-are-votes-anonymous-lets-make-with-the-transparency-and-have-them-publicly).

Comment: it's not easier, because I have to do it in reverse because of the manual temporary `opt out` has to be sent in the correct order to send to the watcher to stop it `watching` , additionally the directory ALWAYS does not exist

Comment: How does a watcher and an opt out concept all of a sudden come into the picture? You don't mention them anywhere in your question, and to be honest, I don't understand your last comment at all. Please be more precise.

Comment: without the "mode" I asked for in the OP the only way is to do `reverse recursion` over the non existent paths i.e in order of the shortest path NOT the longest path, (which is normal in normal recursion), it is highly sub optimal when a simple flag could have accomplished it

Comment: The more comments I read, the less I understand the question. Perhaps you want to solve your original problem (you mentioned something with *watch program* and *berserk*), **not** your attempt to solve it (doing something weird with `CreateDirectory`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> missingDirectories = null;
private void MakeParents(string path)
{
    missingDirectories = new List<string>();
    missingDirectories.Add(path);
    parentDir(path);
    missingDirectories = missingDirectories.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ToList<string>();
    foreach (string directory in missingDirectories)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }        
}
private void parentDir(string path)
{
    string newPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
    if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
    {
        missingDirectories.Add(newPath);
        parentDir(newPath);
    }
}
```

this does it, the issue is that if you want to "gently" roll up the paths one dir at a time making them, something like this is the only way you can do it :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what for you need such method? It seems like you don't want to create all folders needed to create your target folder, like: `C:\this\is\your\path\TargetFolder`
In this case you can just do the following:

```
const string path = @"C:\this\is\your\path";
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, "TargetDirectory"));
}
```

If you have other purpose for that method, please help us to understand which one